# How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation

Tags: c#, generics, reference, xml-documentation

When writing xml documentation you can use `<see cref="something">something</see>`, which works of course. But how do you reference a class or a method with generic types?

```
public class FancyClass<T>
{
  public string FancyMethod<K>(T value) { return "something fancy"; }
}
```

If I was going to write xml documentation somewhere, how would I reference the fancy class? how can I reference a `FancyClass<string>`? What about the method?

For example in a different class I wanted to let the user know that I will return an instance of `FancyClass<int>`. How could I make a see cref thing for that?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

To reference the method:

```
/// <see cref="FancyClass{T}.FancyMethod{K}(T)"/> for more information.
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! It's actually missing from MSDN's page on <see>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx

Comment: I actually believe for it to also work in VS2010 tooltips you need to indicate the number of generic arguments, e.g. "FancyClass`1{T}.FancyMethod`1{K}(T)"

Comment: Not sure what you mean about that. I have never had to add those, and it has always worked for me. Do you have a specific example where it doesn't work? If so, please post it somewhere (or even provide an answer yourself.)

Comment: @Lasse, please see Steve's answer and comments below. Your answer doesn't cover correct Intellisense tooltips.

Answer (score 78):

## TL;DR:

> *"How would I reference `FancyClass<T>`?"*

```
   /// <see cref="FancyClass{T}"/>
```

> *"What about `FancyClass<T>.FancyMethod<K>(T value)`?"*

```
   /// <see cref="FancyClass{T}.FancyMethod{K}(T)"/>
```

> *"How can I reference a `FancyClass<string>`?"*

```
   /// <see cref="SomeType.SomeMethod(FancyClass{string})"/>
   /// <see cref="FancyClass{T}"/> whose generic type argument is <see cref="string"/>
```

While you *can* reference a method whose signature includes `FancyClass<string>` (e.g. as a parameter type), you *cannot* reference such a closed generic type directly. The second example works around that limitation. (This is seen e.g. on the [MSDN refence page for the static `System.String.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784338(v=vs.110).aspx)). :

## XML documentation comment `cref` rules:

- **Surround the generic type parameter list with curly braces `{}`** instead of with `<>` angle brackets. This spares you from escaping the latter as `&lt;` and `&gt;` — remember, documentation comments are XML!
- **If you include a prefix (such as `T:`** for types, `M:` for methods, `P:` for properties, `F:` for fields), the compiler will not perform any validation of the reference, but simply copy the `cref` attribute value straight to the documentation XML output. For this reason, you'll have to use the special ["ID string" syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx) that applies in such files: always use fully-qualified identifiers, and use backticks to reference generic type parameters (`` `n `` on types, ``` ``n ``` on methods).
- **If you omit the prefix**, regular language naming rules apply: you can drop namespaces for which there's a `using` statement, and you can use the language's type keywords such as `int` instead of `System.Int32`. Also, the compiler will check the reference for correctness.

## XML documentation comment `cref` cheat sheet:

```
namespace X
{
    using System;

    /// <see cref="I1"/>  (or <see cref="X.I1"/> from outside X)
    /// <see cref="T:X.I1"/>
    interface I1
    {
        /// <see cref="I1.M1(int)"/>  (or <see cref="M1(int)"/> from inside I1)
        /// <see cref="M:X.I1.M1(System.Int32)"/>
        void M1(int p);

        /// <see cref="I1.M2{U}(U)"/>
        /// <see cref="M:X.I1.M2``1(``0)"/>
        void M2<U>(U p);

        /// <see cref="I1.M3(Action{string})"/>
        /// <see cref="M:X.I1.M3(System.Action{System.String})"/>
        void M3(Action<string> p);
    }

    /// <see cref="I2{T}"/>
    /// <see cref="T:X.I2`1"/>
    interface I2<T>
    {
        /// <see cref="I2{T}.M1(int)"/>
        /// <see cref="M:X.I2`1.M1(System.Int32)"/>
        void M1(int p);

        /// <see cref="I2{T}.M2(T)"/>
        /// <see cref="M:X.I2`1.M2(`0)"/>
        void M2(T p);

        /// <see cref="I2{T}.M3{U}(U)"/>
        /// <see cref="M:X.I2`1.M3``1(``0)"/>
        void M3<U>(U p);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to refer just the `T` part?

Comment: Figured out: `<typeparamref name="T"/>`

Answer (score 50):

```
/// <summary>Uses a <see cref="FancyClass{T}" /> instance.</summary>
```

BTW, it was present in the MSDN documentation of [.Net Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe(VS.80).aspx) and [3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe(VS.85).aspx), but it disapeared in the [version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx)

Comment: what about a spesific instance of T? like string? Maybe not possible?

Comment: what do you mean? You can't declare a specific version, so you can't refer to it either.

Comment: If a method for example only returns List<string> for example. But not important :)

Comment: Yes I was wondering also... resharpers squiggles when writing FancyClass{string} but not when writing FancyClass{String}...

Comment: The reason for the above observation by "Think Before Coding" is that it doesn't work with the c# aliases. For example you need to use `Int32` instead of `int`, `Single` instead of `float` etc. _(Putting this info here in case anyone else stumbles on this)_

Answer (score 26):

None of the answers shown so far work completely for me. ReSharper won't convert the see tag into a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click-able link (e.g. [image: image here]) unless it completely resolves.

If the method in the OP were in a namespace called `Test`, the completely resolved link to the method shown would be:

``` <see cref="M:Test.FancyClass`1.FancyMethod``1(`0)"/> ```

As you may be able to work out, there should only be one backtick before the number of class type parameters, then two backticks before the number of method type parameters, then the parameters are the zero-indexed parameter with the appropriate number of backticks.

So we can see that `FancyClass` has one class type parameter, `FancyMethod` has one type parameter, and an object of the `FancyClass` parameter type will be passed to the method.

As you can more clearly see in this example:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class FancyClass<A, B>
    {
        public void FancyMethod<C, D, E>(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e) { }
    }
}
```

The link becomes:

``` M:Test.FancyClass`2.FancyMethod``3(`0,`1,``0,``1,``2) ```

Or "Class with two type parameters which has a method with three type parameters where the method parameters are `ClassType1`, `ClassType2`, `MethodType1`, `MethodType2`, `MethodType3`"

---

As an additional note, I didn't find this documented anywhere and I'm not a genius, the compiler told me all this. All you have to do is create a test project, [enable XML documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), then insert the code you want to work out a link for, and put the start of an XML doc comment on it (`///`):

```
namespace Test
{
    public class FancyClass<T>
    {
        ///
        public string FancyMethod<K>(T value) { return "something fancy"; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) { }
    }
}
```

Then build your project, and the outputted XML documentation includes the link in the `doc`->`members`->`member` element under the attribute `name`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>Test</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="M:Test.FancyClass`1.FancyMethod``1(`0)">

        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

Comment: This should get more upvotes, especially because of the trick to find the correct notation, without having to go through trial-and-error. Kudos my man

Answer (score 10):

Further from the answers by Lasse and T.B.C:

```
/// <see cref="T:FancyClass`1{T}"/> for more information.

/// <see cref="M:FancyClass`1{T}.FancyMethod`1{K}(T)"/> for more information.
```

will also provide tooltips correctly, whereas their version renders it with the curly braces.

Comment: Using **<see cref="System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}"/>** causes a build-time warning: **XML comment on 'Blah' has syntactically incorrect cref attribute 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<T>** - would you care to elaborate on how one should use this?

Comment: Hi Jakub, This does indeed not seem to work. The only way I can also get tooltips to work correctly is by <see cref="T:<fullTypeName>`1{T}" />.

Comment: thanks, all works correctly now. Both T: and the explicit (and correct!) number of generic parameters are needed to compile without warnings and to have correct Intellisense tooltips. Please update your answer, I will be happy to upvote it, as it is the most complete one of all. BTW, I have yet to see how this looks after the documentation is compiled into HTML/whatever.

Comment: BTW, how do we use it on generic methods in generic classes? None of the above works (Intellisense is not correct): <see cref="M:System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}.Add`1(T)"/>, <see cref="M:System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}.Add`1{T}(T)"/>, <see cref="M:System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}.Add`1(K)"/>, <see cref="M:System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}.Add`1{K}(K)"/>.

Comment: OK, I partially got it. If the method itself is not generic (like in List<T>.Add()), this works: <see cref="M:System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}.Add(T)"/>.

Comment: But if I have a generic class with a generic method (with different generic parameters), it gets tough. E.g. I have: `namespace Foo
{
 public class Bar<T, K>
 {
  public void Baz(T t) { }
  public void Qux(T t) { }
  public void Qux<M>(M m) { }
 }
}`
Both <see cref="M:Foo.Bar`2{T, K}.Qux(T)"/> and <see cref="M:Foo.Bar`2{T, K}.Qux(M)"/> seems to display correctly, but I would expect to be able to use <see cref="M:Foo.Bar`2{T, K}.Qux`1{M}(M)"/> to make in unambiguous. This unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me.  I have **<see cref="M:System.Collections.Generic.List`1{T}"/>** in the comment header for a generic extension method I wrote (converts an ArrayList to a List<T>) but ReSharper flags it as being a syntax error, and IntelliSense just displays it verbatim.  VS 2010/R# 6.1.37.86

Comment: Aha!  I was able to get **<see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1"/>"** to work.  So, using T: instead of the curly braces did the trick.  It does expand out the full namespace, and the trick does not work if you do not include the namespace, so it's not perfect, but it will do.

Comment: @StephenDrew: I recommend you integrate the conclusions arrived at from the comments into your answer. Not many people read all the comments and so some may conclude that your answer doesn't work.

Comment: Tried my best but I only use VS2015 now and cannot verify the correctness :(  Thankfully it is much easier to do this now in VS2015.

Answer (score 7):

```
/// Here we discuss the use of <typeparamref name="TYourExcellentType"/>.
/// <typeparam name="TYourExcellentType">Your exellent documentation</typeparam>
```

Comment: Note that the other answers cover how to reference a generic class, this answer shows you how to reference the type parameter on its own, which happened to be what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <see cref="FancyClass&lt;T>.FancyMethod&lt;K>(T)"/> for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I gave somewhere else. It will work for classes and methods too.

I tried everything on stack overflow to a get results that work under several scenarios. Here's a solution that works for me. (That's subjective concerning anyone else.)

1. Produces clickable links.
2. Hovering over identifiers works.
3. Produces .xml file correctly.
4. Produces no errors in intellisense.
5. Works for nullable generic type parameters.
6. Works in Resharper and it's built-in XML Doc window (Resharper -> Edit -> Show Quick Documentation)
7. Works in XAM Doc Preview for Atomineer Pro Documentaion Visual Studio Extension.
8. Works with a generic type of a generic type.

Example #1

```
  /// <summary>
  ///  This instance field holds a reference to the
  ///  <see cref="ConcurrentDictionary{Decimal, Boolean}"/> as
  ///  <see cref="T:ConcurrentDictionary&lt;decimal, bool?&gt;"/> that contains
  ///  the list of all PDF's that are currently opened and being displayed.
  /// </summary>
  private ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, bool?> openedPdfs = default!;

  Note: 
    The ConcurrentDictionary{Decimal, Boolean} will correctly produce a
    clickable link of ConcurrentDictionary{TKey, TValue} on hovering while
    T:ConcurrentDictionary&lt;decimal, bool?&gt; makes sure the reader gets
    information on what type TKey and TValue are.
```

Example # 2 (using "T")

```
  /// <summary>
  ///  This instance field holds a reference to the
  ///  <see cref="ConcurrentDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> as
  ///  <see cref="T:ConcurrentDictionary&lt;decimal, bool?&gt;"/> that contains
  ///  the list of all PDF's that are currently opened and being displayed.
  /// </summary>
  private ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, bool?> openedPdfs = default!;
```