# using see cref with < > characters in XML Documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-comments, xml-documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation)

i have been using the see cref tag and it works great but now i need to include a generic list of string[] in the see cref but the documentation doesn't correctly render.

```
    /// <returns>A <see cref="List<string[]>" /> that .......
```

I presume its something to do with the <   and >   and maybe []

Is this allowed, is there a work around?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
/// <returns>A <see cref="List{T}" /> that</returns>
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, but in the produced documentation it displays this  A [!:List<System.String>] that      - Notice the !:

Comment: Try `List{String}`. It works fine.

Comment: You can find more details on syntax here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe(VS.85).aspx