# How to show content inside see cref in XML comment from Intellisense and DocFx?

Tags: c#, comments, xml-documentation, xml-comments, docfx

I have used XML comment on a property which is a type of List.

However when I hover my mouse to that property, Visual Studio shows it as `List<T>`.

When I build the documentation with docFx, it still renders the comment as `List<T>` instead of `List<ClassXXXX>`.

I have tried the solution recommended by [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828075/using-see-cref-with-characters-in-xml-documentation) here but it does not work.

Here is the XML comment with C# code for your reference:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets and sets the <see cref="List{T}"/> .
/// </summary>
public List<ClassXXXX> ListFoo { get; set; }
```

What can I do in the XML comment so I can see `List<ClassXXXX>` in the intellisense and documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Set the text you want explicitly in the <see> tag:

```
/// Gets and sets the <see cref="List{T}">List&lt;ClassXXXX&gt;</see> .
```

You cannot specify List<ClassXXXX> directly in the cref attribute. The cref is a reference to a type definition and to its documentation. There's no type List<ClassXXXX> and no documentation for it. There's only List<T> to which you can create a link. But the link text may be anything you need.