# How to make a documentation for a function which has an IDictionary<TKey, TValue> parameter?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/c-how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation)

I want to create a short documentation (in VS2010) for my static function which has one `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` parameter.

for example :

```
public static string newDocument(IDictionary<string,string> listMap)
{
//the code
}
```

I want to create a documentation in VS2010 ,when you type `/` three times then will generate automatically like as below :

```
/// <summary>
/// create something
/// </summary>
/// <param name="listMap">Text here</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string newDocument(IDictionary<string,string> listMap)
    {
    //the code
    }
```

I want to write in this way: the dictionary `key` is something and the dictionary `value` is something else.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [StyleCop rules guide](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/48036) doesn't not provide any rule for documenting IDictionaries. It's trivial, but I suggest the following:

```
/// <param name="listMap">List map parameter representing xxx. The keys in the dictionary are XXX and the values are YYY</param>
```

Comment: I knew that but ... maybe I will this format if there are no other way