# Escape generic type parameter in <code> XML summary tag

Tags: c#, .net-core

I get an error that "XML element is not closed". I'm not sure how to escape a generic parameter in `<code>`.

```
/// <summary>
///     The configuration of the api specific
/// </summary>
/// <Remark>
///     Allows for dependency injecting configurations
/// </Remark>
/// <code>
/// private IOptionsMonitor<ApiConfig> _options;
/// </code>
```

Comment: Are you looking for `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: @Amy it did the trick. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generics in XML documentation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412865/generics-in-xml-documentation-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doc comments are XML, and need to be treated as XML.  The `<` and `>` characters need to be escaped using `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.