# VB.NET: How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation

Tags: vb.net, generics, reference, xml-documentation

**Note**: This is a copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/c-how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation) but for Visual Basic instead C#.

When writing XML documentation you can use `<see cref="something">something</see>`, which works of course. But how do you reference a class or a method with generic types?

```vb
Public Class FancyClass(Of T)

  Public Function  FancyMethod(value As T) As String
    Return "something fancy"
  End Function

End Class
```

If I was going to write xml documentation somewhere, how would I reference the fancy class? how can I reference a `FancyClass(Of String)`? What about the method?

For example in a different class I wanted to let the user know that I will return an instance of `FancyClass(Of Integer)`. How could I make a `see cref` thing for that?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you cannot do this thing in VS2012, but it has been fixed in VS2013; you can simply write `<see cref="FancyClass(Of T)" />`.

Comment: Define 'fixed' ... it seems to crash VS every other/3rd time I write a 'cref=' !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to write something like that :

```
''' <summary>
''' A great fancy class.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">Generic stuff ....</typeparam>
Public Class FancyClass(Of T)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A fancy method that do fancy operation.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="value">The value.</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function FancyMethod(value As T) As String
        Return "something fancy"
    End Function

End Class
```

The xml documentation must talk about your generic class. You will never reference `FancyClass(Of String)` : this is not a class.

Comment: I wanted to write something like `<see cref="FancyClass{T}" />` (this is the C# way) in an xml-doc comment. It seems that this issue has been fixed in VS2013.

Comment: And by the way, `FancyClass(Of String` is certainly a class (you can create instances of that class); `FancyClass(Of T)` is just a class template; you cannot create object instances of that thing.

Comment: Yep, when i said it's not a class, i thought in xml-doc way : you can't write `<see cref="FancyClass(Of String)" />`