# How to use IEnumerable<String> in documenting code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I have this method which I am trying to generate documentation.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method demonstrates taking a Func as argument and perform that action(Func) on a list of strings.</summary>
    /// <param name="listOfStrings"> ... </param>
    /// <param name="ActionToPerformOnEach"> ... </param>
    /// <returns>Returns an <see cref="IEnumerable{String}" /> which has elements that resulted due to the Func action </returns>
    public static IEnumerable<String> ActOnListWithFunc(List<string> listOfStrings, Func<string, string> ActionToPerformOnEach) {
        foreach (string s in listOfStrings) {
            string actedString = ActionToPerformOnEach(s);
            yield return actedString;
        }
    }
```

This generates documentation like this (only **Return Value** section is shown)

```
Return Value
Type: IEnumerable<String>
Returns an IEnumerable<T> which has elements that resulted due to the Func action
```

Where I am describing the return value of the method, I want to use **IEnumerable<string>** but if you look the desscription it is generating **IEnumerable<T>**. The **Type:** (second line above) although is been picked up properly as **IEnumerable<string>**. Just the description line for the return value is not correct.

How do we describe **IEnumerable<string>** or **IEnumerable<int>** or any other specific type of enumeration in descriptions of parameters or return values, that is betwween **<param> </param> or <returns> </returns>** tags of the Method being documentated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation)

Comment: I am already using <see cref="IEnumerable{String}"> in my Returns attribute for the method, but its not showing the specific generic type (string). Please see the third line of the second patch of code posted. Its reads IEnumerable<T> instead of IEnumerable<String>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can show the appropriate text using `<see cref="IEnumerable{String}">IEnumerable&lt;string&gt;</see>`.  However the link will still be to [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as there is no specific documentation for `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: I think, Link to IEnumerable<T> may be acceptable, but those character entities (&lt; and &gt;) are a little ugly. But in any case your solution does work and I get IEnumerable<string> as desired. Still I will wait for some time, for alternatives if any, before marking as accepted solution.

Answer (score 4):

We would just write

```cs
/// <returns>Returns an <see cref="IEnumerable{T}" /> of type <see cref="string"/> which has elements that resulted due to the Func action.</returns>
```

This creates a reference to both `IEnumerable<out T>` and `string`.

The solution proposed by John Koemer has the disadvantage that IntelliSense does not do anything with the `IEnumerable%lt;string%gt;` part.

[image: IntelliSense showing listOfStrings argument]