# XML Documentation for "De-genericized" generics

Tags: c#, documentation, documentation-generation, xml-documentation

I was looking at [How to reference generic classes and methods in xml documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation) but it seems to be not quite getting what I'd like to properly set up in my XML documentation.

I have a helper method that converts an `IDictionary<string, object>` to an `IDictionary<string, string>` to address some compatibility issues.

I want to add XML documentation properly, but I'm getting squiggly lines under my text when I write `<see cref="IDictionary{string, object}"/>`.  So I tried to do as suggested (kinda) in the above referenced post: `<see cref="IDictionary{TKey:System.String, TValue:System.Object}"/>`... but that doesn't seem to work either.

I want to properly document in XML "Converts an `IDictionary<string, object>` to an `IDictionary<string, string>` to address some compatibility issues."  How to do this?

Comment: You can specify exact type as normal text and additionally reference generic method as in the link.

Comment: Well theoretically I could do it all as normal text, though it seems a bit wrong... but are you suggesting there is no mechanism for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: And what are you trying to do exactly? It would be nice if you show methods signatures and complete comments text. You can reference `T` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40531753/1997232) in your link) if this is the problem.

Comment: Hmm that does not seem to work, as far as I can figure out how it should be.