# How to reference type parameter in XML documentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-documentation

How do you reference a type parameter in XML code documentation? For instance, this code

```cs
/// <summary>
/// An interface.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TInterface">Type paramter.</typeparam>
public interface IFace<TInterface>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does the thing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMethod">Different from <see cref="TInterface"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>An integer.</returns>
    int SomeMethod<TMethod>();
}
```

Gives a warning about `typeparam name="TMethod"`:

> XML comment has cref attribute 'TInterface' that refers to a type paramter.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation) asks about referencing a generic type, but I want to reference the type parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `see cref`, the [`typeparamref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/typeparamref) should be used instead:

```
/// <summary>
/// An interface.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TInterface">Type paramter.</typeparam>
public interface IFace<TInterface>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does the thing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMethod">Different from <typeparamref name="TInterface"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>An integer.</returns>
    int SomeMethod<TMethod>();
}
```