# Documentation Comments in C# - Can't use '<' or '>' in Summary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

Can anybody tell me how to get this working?

```
 /// <summary>
 /// I want to write: List<T>
 /// </summary>
```

Any time I use '<' or '>' VS gives up on me...
`<c>` or `<code>` will not do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532166/how-to-reference-generic-classes-and-methods-in-xml-documentation

Comment: @Matthew That's specifically about `<see cref=""/>`, and this question is not

Comment: So far you're getting a couple different approaches, and both will work for the example you've given.. but IMO, the `<see cref=""/>` makes more sense if you're actually wanting to reference a particular class. Of course if you just want a literal `<` or `>`, then the `&lt;` and `&gt;` approach is pretty much the only option (eg. if you wanted to say something like "Checks if a > b").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular xml escaping:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// I want to write: List&lt;T&gt;
 /// </summary>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// I want to write: <see cref="System.Collections.Generic.List{T}"/>
/// </summary>
```

Comment: This extends Sean's answer

Comment: @user947737: Not really. This includes an actual type reference in the comment instead of a random string.

Comment: @user947737 - I disagree. It's a totally different approach and deserves to be a separate answer. They address different concerns and this is the appropriate approach IMO, given the situation in your question.

Comment: @both: Sean answered my question, this is added value - the extension is to my knowledge!

Comment: IMHO, In this particular case, this is a better answer. For a random `<` or `>` (or any other xml-breaking char for that matter), use xml entities as in Sean's answer.